# How to permanently remove a linearlayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

In this program, I want to delete `ll2` (LinearLayout) when mButton is pressed. I.e I don't want this layout to appear the second time I enter this activity. When I push the button, the layout is gone for as long as I am in the activity, but when I come back into the activity, the layout is there.

How do I permanently delete it? Thanks in advance!

```
LinearLayout ll,ll2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    location_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.location_btn);
    menu_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_menu);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttone);
    mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittexte);
    ll2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llayout);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            number = mEdit.getText().toString();
            mEdit.setText("");
            ll2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll2.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        }
    });
}
```

My layout file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/llayout"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittexte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:id="@+id/buttone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep a `SharedPreference` and save the state that you have pressed the button earlier. Then each time you enter the activity, check the value stored in your `SharedPreference` and if its found that the button is already pressed before, just hide the `LinearLayout`.

```
LinearLayout ll,ll2;
SharedPreference pref; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    pref = getSharedPreferences("MyApplication", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    location_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.location_btn);
    menu_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_menu);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttone);
    mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittexte);
    ll2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llayout);

    // Check the preference value when activity is launched each time and hide of the button was pressed before
    if(pref.getBoolean("ButtonPressed", false)) ll2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            number = mEdit.getText().toString();
            mEdit.setText("");
            // Save the sate of the button pressed in the SharedPreference
            pref.edit().putBoolean("ButtonPressed", true).apply();

            ll2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

Comment: To add to this, if you are only showing a view sometimes, and never want to show it again after some action, you should look at using a ViewStub and inverting your logic to "if button has not been clicked yet, inflate view, otherwise do nothing".

Comment: Great to know that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving a boolean in `SharedPreferences`...
For e.g. 
Keep the boolean as `false` in the beginning.

As soon as you press the button, remove the View (LinearLayout), change the boolean to `true` & save it to SharedPreferences...

In the onCreate(),
try as

```
if(booleanisTrue) {
   ll2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   ll2.removeAllViewsInLayout();
 }
```